# displaying results vertically in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm enamored with mysql's \G feature which I find very useful  when SELECTing from tables with many columns. Is there a similar feature in oracle which displays each column on its own line? How do people normally deal with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Tom Kyte's print_table procedure](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958)

For example:

```
SQL> exec print_table('select * from emp where empno=7839')
EMPNO                         : 7839
ENAME                         : KING
JOB                           : PRESIDENT
MGR                           :
HIREDATE                      : 17-nov-1981 00:00:00
SAL                           : 100
COMM                          : 500
DEPTNO                        : 10
-----------------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```