# Ugly formatting in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

It is really annoying that when I run a select command in SQL*Plus such as:

```
SELECT * FROM books;
```

The output is really badly formatted and unreadable (row cells are not in a row but separated by line breaks etc):

[image]

How can I configure it to show SELECT results in a nicer way?

EDIT:

This is my login.sql file contents:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET PAGESIZE 999
SET LINESIZE 132
```

EDIT2:

Affer increasing the LINESIZE:

```
SET LINESIZE 32000
```

It now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228680/displaying-results-vertically-in-oracle.

Comment: Lots of overlap/duplication with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771573

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Increase the linesize, e.g `SET LINESIZE 32000`

or use `SET WRAP OFF` (but this will truncate long values)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok this helped a bit but it still looks horrific. Look at the second image I added to my question.

Comment: @Richard: did you try `SET WRAP OFF`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes that made it nicer but it only shows first two columns now!

Comment: @Richard Knop: I think it's high time you defined the `nicer way` bit of your question more precisely. :)

Comment: @Richard Knop: as long as you don't increase the width of your terminal I don't think SQL*Plus will ever make your console window showing a horizontal scrollbar. But why don't you use a GUI tool that can makes dealing with these kind of tables a lot easier?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I'm just learning and following a book where SQL*Plus is used. But don't worry, I have figured a way to make it look a little bit more readable. It's not perfect but oh well.

Comment: If you want to make it permanent (i.e. every time you log into SQL*Plus), add those lines to *glogin.sql* in **$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin**.

Comment: Thanks man - REALLY helped me. I was getting WAY too frustrated with the regular formatting.

Comment: I have been pasting my format script in every session.  On windows, I had to use login.sql.  glogin.sql is for Unix.

Answer (score 13):

SQL*Plus is a simple command line tool.  It's not really intended for pretty reporting.  However, it does have some formatting commands, which are documented in the SQL*Plus User's Guide.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081008).

For instance you might choose to format the TITLE column to display only the first twenty characters and display the SUMMARY column in its entirety like this:

```
COLUMN title FORMAT a20 TRUNCATED 
COLUMN summary FORMAT a4o WORD_WRAPPED
```

This will allow you to see your query laid out more neatly without embedding formatting commands in its projection.

Alternatively, use an IDE such as Quest's TOAD or Oracle's own SQL Developer.  These tools include a query browser which automagically displays our query results in a more pleasing grid.  (Other similar tools are available).

Comment: I remember back in school we also used SQL*Plus and there was a single command we used which made tables display nicely formatted. I can't remember what it was. And setting word wrapping for every column is not very good when you have many columns and more tables.

Comment: @RichardKrop - I agree setting formatting for each column will get tedious.  That's why it's common to use scripts for commonly run queries.  I'm really not sure what that magical single omni-formatting command would have been.  Perhaps it was a script which your teachers had written?

Answer (score 10):

Make a script like below

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE="/tmp/queryResult.csv"
sqlplus -s /nolog << !EOF!
connect username/password

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET LINESIZE 250
SET NUMWIDTH 5
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set echo off
set heading on
set headsep off
set wrap off
SET COLSEP ","
column Title format a22
column Summary format a15

SPOOL $FILE

Select * from books;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
!EOF!
```

Save script in a file namely sqlscript.sql
set permission on file

```
chmode +x sqlscript.sql
```

run the script and pipe to less command

```
./sqlscript.sql | less -S
```

"S" option will allow you to scroll with arrow keys, if output is longer than columns set in terminal.

Alternatively you can download and open FILE="/tmp/queryResult.csv" in text editor of your choice.

Adjust the LINESIZE,NUMWIDTH, column character size (a22) as per your requirement

Answer (score 8):

Some may not like this advice (I can think of a few DBAs who LOVE SqlPlus), but you may want to use an IDE like [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/) or [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).  If you're new to Oracle, sqlplus will make you feel like you just jumped back in time!  IMO, spend your time learning Oracle, not SQLPlus. (oh, and read the [Concepts guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage) while playing around in your IDE of choice)

Answer (score 6):

Just define the column widths so that it fits the actual content of the columns

```
col column_name1 format a20  -- sets column to be 20 characters wide
col column_name2 format a15  -- sets column to be 15 characters wide
set line 80

select column_name1, column_name2 from books;
```

This should help you out.

Answer (score 5):

This can make output more pretty:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF
SET COLSEP ' '
```

Source: http://larig.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/formatting-oracle-output-in-sqlplus/

Answer (score 5):

Csv style, but clean:

```
SQL> set markup csv on
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61237983/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to all these answers:

```
set colsep "&TAB"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT ISBN, SUBSTR(TITLE, 0, 16), SUBSTR(SUMMARY, 0, 16), DATE_PUBL, PAGE_COUNT FROM books;
```

Answer (score 0):

When sqlplus shows so many dashes that means your linesize is to large. at least larger than that of your console -> decrease linesize until it fits width of the console.