# PL/SQL Select values in rows (vertical)

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I'm trying to select values from my DB. Right now I get the result set horizontal displayed but I want it in a vertical way.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

With this Query the result Looks like this:

> ```
> ID | Name | Age | City_id
> 1    A       20    2
> ```

But I want it looking like this:

> ```
> 1
> A
> 20
> 2
> ```

Is there a solution for my Problem.

I tryied to use `UNPIVOT` but didn't work

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/2228994/18747

Comment: do you really need to have a one-column CHAR rowset returned from your query? If not, I'd recommend to do that in the presentation layer of the application. If you need it at design time, and you're using SQL Developer, there's also the "single record view" in the table viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xml and xquery .

```
select * from xmltable('for $i in ./ROWSET/ROW/* return $i' 
passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from all_objects where rownum < 2'))
     columns colum_name varchar2(100) path 'local-name()'
             ,         text varchar2(100) path 'text()'
     );
```

In your case, you can use it like below

```
select text from
(     
select * from 
xmltable('for $i in ./ROWSET/ROW/* return $i' 
passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from myTable where rownum < 2'))
     columns colum_name varchar2(100) path 'local-name()'
             ,text varchar2(100) path 'text()'
             )
 )
```

Comment: Excellent query. +1. Makes my `union` query look like from stone age :)
Edited to suit more to OP's need.

Comment: How can I put this query in a VARHCAR2 variable? As soon I add it like << myVariable := 'Select text...'>> I get the error that somehting with "$i" is wrong

Comment: IF I execute the Query manuelly it works perfectly. As soon I use it in my code I get the error ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement doesn't make much sense, but what you want to achieve, could be done by `Union`

Try this

```
 select cast(id as varchar2(20)) as col1 from myTable
 union all
 select Name from mytable
 union all
 select cast(Age as varchar2(20))  from mytable
 union all
 select cast(City_id as varchar2(20)) from mytable
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this example on XE Database, table employees. You can use Pivot Clause:

```
select first_name from employees
pivot(
sum(salary) for department_id in (50)
);
```

output:

```
   Bruce
    Luis
    Den
    Shanta
    Renske
    Oliver
    Clara
    Alexis
...
```

.

```
PIVOT
(
PIVOT_CLAUSE
PIVOT_FOR_CLAUSE
PIVOT_IN_CLAUSE
)
```

CLAUSE - it's a function (here: sum())

FOR_CLAUSE - determines data which are basis for crated columns

IN_CLAUSE - determines range of this data (here: department_id, could be hire_date, eye color, dog type etc)

Comment: This gets the same output as `select first_name from employees`. Possibly in a different order. You aren't using the pivoted column value. And it isn't translating columns to rows - which would be an unpivot.